# Ошибка при генерации строки в Spring Web MVC

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, spring-mvc

Есть у меня пара методов, обрабатывающих запросы через Spring MVC.

Выглядят они так:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String update(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    Meal meal = get(id);    //отдельный метод
    model.addAttribute("meal", meal);
    return "mealForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(HttpServletRequest request) {
    int userId = AuthorizedUser.id();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

    Meal meal = new Meal();
    meal.setId(id);
    meal.setUser(new User());
    meal.setCalories(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("calories")));
    meal.setDescription(request.getParameter("description"));
    meal.setDateTime(LocalDateTime.parse(request.getParameter("dateTime")));

    log.info("update {} with id={} for userId={}", meal, id, userId);
    assureIdConsistent(meal, id);
    service.update(meal, userId);
    return "meals";
}
```

При вызове ссылки

```
<td><a href="update/${meal.id}">Update</a></td>
```

обрабатывает метод `@RequestMapping(value = "/update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)`, потом генерирует View с формой изменения параметров, отправляет его по адресу: `http://localhost:8081/topjava/update/100007` и по нажатию Save отправляет POST-запрос в метод `@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)`. Проблема в том, что ожидается адрес

```
http://localhost:8081/topjava/update
```

(который потом будет обработан вторым методом), а получается

```
http://localhost:8081/topjava/update/update
```

то есть, добавляется лишний `/update` с ошибкой 405 (не находит метод).

Как мне побороть эту проблему и убрать лишний `/update`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update/${meal.id}">Update</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Сергей!

Answer (score 0):

думаю, достаточно поставить слэш перед update в адресе ссылки, чтобы адрес воспринимался не как относительный:

```
<a href="/update/${meal.id}">Update</a>
```